# Can I host my own instance of Trello?

Tags: trello

I like using Trello, but my company might block the site at any time so I am uncomfortable really depending on it. Is there anyway to buy a version to host within my company?

Comment: Try  https://wekan.io/  (note you can also get it hosted on sandstorm.io)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, currently there is no ability to do that and there are no plans to provide something like this either.

Quote from the [Common Questions](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/) post on the Trello blog:

> **Can I install this on my own server?**
>   No.  I can say with a lot of certainty that we don’t plan on doing
>   this.  We believe that the majority of people are becoming more
>   comfortable hosting their services and the boost in dev productivity
>   we get by only having one platform to test on is immense.

Comment: Additionally, there are no plans to offer a self-hosted version in the future. I'm a member of the Trello team.

Comment: @Rich Armstrong - do you know if there any open source clones that would allow self hosting.  this is a big blocker for us

Comment: I'm not sure that asking someone who works on Trello for recommendations of open source clones is going to be very effective! :-)

Comment: We don't mind! At Fog Creek, our commercial products compete with open source every day, so it's not a dirty word. We also contribute heavily to some open source projects (like Mercurial) If history is any guide, open source is not exactly synonymous with intuitive interfaces and beautiful design, so I'm not sure one will ever emerge for Trello, considering that's its main selling point. @leora, sorry this is a blocker for you!

Comment: @leora Please don't use comments for chat

Comment: I know you have answered that question allready, but it was nearly 1 year ago.
so I'm asking again : Is there a plan to offer a self-hosted version ? or is the answer still no ?
thanks a lot

Comment: @A.Harris All I can say is that there is still no mention of self-hosted Trello versions on either the [FAQ](https://trello.com/guide) or the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)

Comment: I work at Fog Creek.  While I hate to say never: we are never going to make a self-hosted version of Trello.  We're working on data export and import and corporate user account integration, but having Trello be a single, centralized thing is a huge part of what Trello *is*.  We're not going to compromise on that.

Comment: It's Trello's prerogative of course, but the argument that it's about dev productivity is more or less moot if distributed as a docker app.

Comment: Wekan is open-source https://github.com/wekan/wekan

Comment: Clearly this is simply the profit motive at work; as other users have said, the "testing", "UI", and "centralised" arguments are all logically flimsy lies. The work all the developers & designers poured into creating the perfect kanban app is autocratically controlled by Fog Creek's owners, who seek to profit by denying the fruits of their employees' labour (the source code) from the rest of the world. The software community loves to think it is "apolitical", yet will bend over backwards to accomodate massive inefficiencies and setbacks from the property-owner class.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you give [Teambox](http://teambox.com/) a try? It's great! I personally find it better than Trello. It has an [open source version](https://github.com/teambox/teambox) as well, for you to host on your own private machines.

Comment: Note that the open source version of Teambox is only v3 which doesn't look anything like the site version (which is v4).

It took me a few weeks to get it all setup. It was such a disappointment.

Comment: @Ian Give OTM a try https://www.online-task-manager.com/ I believe they are planning to release a self hosted version sometime in the future.

Comment: Teambox has become Redbooth which no longer provides self-hosting / open source. It's old code is still open-source however.

Answer (score 7):

There is an open source clone of Trello, that is actually quite good! It's called Kanban, and it is shockingly similar feel to Trello

https://github.com/somlor/kanban

Very cool. It only has the basic features at the moment (attachments, calendar, tagging, etc aren't there) but it does boards comments and cards very well, and that might be all you need.

It's also noticibly faster than Trello, and you can put it in your LAN

Comment: This clone is pretty nice with the basic visuals, but the actual app is pretty lacking. There is no way in the UI to create new boards. And the project is in general pretty immature.

That said if anyone wants to build an open source clone the UI on this is probably a great starting point.

Comment: @Boushley Give OTM a try online-task-manager.com I believe they are planning to release a self hosted version sometime in the future

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, check out

https://github.com/libreboard/libreboard

which is like trello is derived from

Comment: Now it's `Wekan`, formerly `LibreBoard`, is an open-source and collaborative Trello -like kanban board application.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no self-hosted Trello, there is a Trello clone called Libreboard. They actually [received a DMCA letter](https://github.com/libreboard/libreboard/issues/92) from Trello. But the repo seems to have moved [here](http://git.libreboard.com/libreboard/libreboard/blob/master/README.md).

EDIT: They seem to be back on [Github](https://github.com/libreboard/libreboard).

Answer (score 0):

If a user of the trello (company owner in this case) user is surpassing the limit of actions and triggers and Trello can't offer an individual copy of it product for them (understandable). I think a good approach would be that trello creates a new plan where they offer a server package with an extra boost of unlimited actions and triggers. This server would live in TRELLO buildings but would belong to the company user.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! That might be a good idea, but it doesn't really answer the question. Please have a look at the Help Center article [answer].